# Is it possible to use current Buildroot for Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: buildroot, raspberry-pi2

http://git.buildroot.net/buildroot/tree/board/raspberrypi/readme.txt states the following — where the last line is the interesting one:

> The raspberrypi_defconfig configuration is a minimal configuration
>   with all that is required to bring the Raspberry Pi up. You should
>   base your work on this defconfig:
>
> $ make raspberrypi_defconfig
>
> Alternatively, if you want to test support for the Device Tree:
>
> $ make raspberrypi_dt_defconfig
>
> For Raspberry Pi 2 use a different defconfig:
>
> $ make raspberrypi2_defconfig

Is that raspberrypi2_defconfig **required** to use buildroot on an Raspberry Pi 2, or does it just contain RPi2 optimizations? The reason why I'm asking is that I don't find that configuration in the latest stable version of Buildroot, and the current git version abort the build with an

```
"HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404: Not Found"
```

====================================

Console printout after second build crasch:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fredrik/buildroot/output/build/host-lzop-1.03'
>>> linux 2c4959b772a35d9d459b0a92f39bb066e9a44d37 Downloading
Doing shallow clone
Cloning into bare repository 'linux-2c4959b772a35d9d459b0a92f39bb066e9a44d37'...
WARNING: gnome-keyring:: couldn't connect to: /tmp/keyring-BVQjKJ/pkcs11: No such file or directory
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1077 to 570 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (gzip 1086 to 577 bytes)
remote: Counting objects: 223619, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (141382/141382), done.
remote: Total 223619 (delta 145491), reused 134621 (delta 80295), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (223619/223619), 271.86 MiB | 1.80 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (145491/145491), done.
warning: Remote branch 2c4959b772a35d9d459b0a92f39bb066e9a44d37 not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
fatal: not a tree object
--2015-04-13 00:26:38--  http://sources.buildroot.net/linux-2c4959b772a35d9d459b0a92f39bb066e9a44d37.tar.gz
Resolving sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)... 176.9.16.109
Connecting to sources.buildroot.net (sources.buildroot.net)|176.9.16.109|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-04-13 00:26:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.

make: *** [/home/fredrik/buildroot/output/build/linux-2c4959b772a35d9d459b0a92f39bb066e9a44d37/.stamp_downloaded] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not mandatory, but it's a prebuilt configuration that ensures that you will have a working system.

When pasting errors, please include more lines (like 50-100 lines), because the real error is not this 404. It's earlier, the fact that it can't find in the RPi kernel Git repository the commit we're looking for. Try again with the latest Buildroot, I think we've updated the raspberrypi2_defconfig with a more recent RPi kernel commit.

Comment: It builds now. Thanks! Will try to run it on target tomorrow.

Comment: Ouch. I think it's the same again. It worked yesterday. I'll post the log in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the RPi kernel git repository is often rebased against the linux-stable kernel, which means that the commit that buildroot refers to is no longer accessible.

The solution is to use a stable branch from the RPi kernel git repository, where no rebasing is done. This is done by [this patch](http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/466042/).

Comment: It builds now. I will try it on target soon.

Comment: I just want to add that I've now successfully run the system on target.